# Conflict's with jquery script

Tags: jquery

```
<script src="js1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Please help me, i am using the above script and at same time my drop down menu stops working.

Comment: what error are you getting and please upload your code.

Comment: when i use this scrpt at same time then didnt work the dropdown menu, one for lightbox

Comment: Can't you just remove the first one?

Comment: when i remove first one then not working lightbox

Comment: Why are you using two versions of jQuery?

Comment: bcoz of there is dropdown menu and lightbox in same page

Answer (score 0):

You can try `jQuery.noConflict` methos to resolve version conficts.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="js1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>var $j = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
```

Now you can use **$j** for lightbox plugin.

Hope it helps.